# jQuery append list of x elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to understand how can I make a list of `x` elements when a value change. 
Let's go with the example

**HTML**

```
<select class="num">
 <option value="1">1</option>
 <option value="2">2</option>
 <option value="3">3</option>
 <option value="4">4</option>
 <option value="5">5</option>
</select>

<div class="list"></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
<script>
    $('.num').change(function() {
      num_val = $(this).val(); // get the number of the elements that will be shown
      for (i =0; i == num_val; i++) { // I do a for loop for append each div to the list but it doesn't work it's show me just 1.
         $('.list').append('<div>' + i + '</div>'); 
      }
    });
</script>
```

So, how can I display `X` number element equal to the value on select input?

Comment: `for (i =0; i< num_val; i++)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change you html into:

```
<select class="num">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```

or the value will be always 1, and you'll add only one element.

Than cange you loop condition into:

```
 $('.num').change(function () {
     num_val = $(this).val(); // get the number of te elements that will be shown
     $('.list').empty();
     for (i = 0; i < num_val; i++) { // i do a for loop for append each div to the list but it doesn't work it's show me just 1.
         $('.list').append('<div>' + i + '</div>');
     }
 });
```

I used `$('.list').empty();` to clear the list before append elements to it.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/Y79ec/

Comment: @Gilbert you are welcome! If solved consider to tick the answer as solved

Answer (score 1):

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/IpUsUfO/3/edit)

<sub>note the changed value</sub>

```
<option value="3">3</option>
```

```
$('.num').change(function() {  
      for (var i=0; i<this.value; i++) {
         $('.list').append('<div>' + (i+1) + '</div>'); 
      }
});
```

Performance-wise it's a bad idea to catch your *.list* element and create HTML elements
all over again in a loop, so a better approach would be:

```
var list = '';

$('.num').change(function() {  
      for (var i=0; i<this.value; i++) {
         list += '<div>' + (i+1) + '</div>';
      }
      $('.list').append( list ); // only once after the loop.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

html code

```
<select class="num">
     <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="2">2</option>
     <option value="3">3</option>
     <option value="4">4</option>
     <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```

javascript code

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
         $('.num').change(function() {
             $('.list').html(''); 
              var num_val = parseInt($(this).val()); // get the number of te elements that will be shown
              console.log(num_val);
              for (var i =1; i <= num_val; i++) {
                 $('.list').append('<div>' + i + '</div>'); 
              }
        });
    });
```